# Restrict publishing code to deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots, azure-security

We have multiple slots for the same app service. We would like to restrict users by not allowing them to publish code to staging and production slots from visual studio. I gave reader access to the staging and prod slots but the user is still able to publish the code. Is there any other settings/configurations we may need to do.

Comment: To check if your Reader access is working, in the portal, are they able to go to the slot and view the App Settings? That's not supposed to work when you're a reader, so that's a good sanity check.

Comment: Yes they can view the app settings. Infact they can even publish pages to Staging and Prod slots.

Comment: The point is to isolate the issue, so no need to re-add publishing in the equation, as that's what your main description already says! :) So you're saying that your reader user can view/modify things like connection strings? If so, then you did not correctly make them a reader. I tested the scenario and it works fine for me.

Comment: Not sure what the issue might be then. I gave the user reader on the staging slot and owner on the test slot. He has reader on the resource group on which previously he was owner. Does it take a while to update the permissions?

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. Please try isolating. e.g create a new empty web app and add same permission. Does it do the right thing?

Comment: [Update]: The settings worked for me and have been able to apply security policies around app services.

Comment: Great, so what was wrong?

Comment: Not sure. I removed the account and re-added. Started working.